# Have data from a list in memory even when the program closes

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a list with some data (strings):

```
Anna
Amy
Johnny
John
```

Then I have a method that gets the data from the list and writes it to a listView.

But when i close the form all the data in the list disappears (which is obvious), so I wonder how I smoothly can remember the data in the list so that next time I run the program, the program remembers the data writes the items in the list to the ListView directly.

Comment: Do you mean write it to files?

Comment: Ofcourse, write to files and then read them back

Comment: Have tried that but that didnt work in my program beacause I have an ID number for each name wich makes that a bit complicated so I need to do it as i described.

Comment: What do you mean you are finding it difficult to IDs in a file ? I suggest you create a POJO of data that you want to persist. Then write the object of this POJO to file.

Comment: you can use .txt files: just make a newline for every name and pass the ID to that name in the same line, when reading out that file split the line to ID and name...

Comment: OOPS !!! I thought its a JAVA question. Please ignore the POJO thing. You can simply go with text-files.

Answer (score 0):

You need to persist your data somewhere.

In decreasing complexity I'd suggest...

1. a relational database (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233816(v=vs.80).aspx)
2. save locally to file (XML for example http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815813)
3. write to text file (http://www.csharp-station.com/HowTo/ReadWriteTextFile.aspx)

From link (3) this shows how easily you can read to and write to a file

```
namespace csharp_station.howto
{
class TextFileWriter
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // create a writer and open the file
        TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter("date.txt");

        // write a line of text to the file
        tw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);

        // close the stream
        tw.Close();
    }
}
}



class TextFileReader
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // create reader & open file
        Textreader tr = new StreamReader("date.txt");

        // read a line of text
        Console.WriteLine(tr.ReadLine());

        // close the stream
        tr.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want the data to remain after the application executable has exited in preparation for when you next run it then you'll need to look at a permanent storage solution e.g. database or file. You won't be able to leave the data resident in memory, even if NET compartmentalisation would allow you to, you wouldn't know where to look for it.

If you mean that you want the data available after you close a form, but still have the application running then you'll need to make the data available at a higher level or rather in another class that remains in scope even when the form in question exits.

Answer (score 0):

For small application specific data like this, I would recommend using C#'s built in persistent settings. These will save to an application config file.

You can access them as below:

```
// Access the property
Properties.Settings.Default.SettingName = "I'm a string";

// Make sure to save before you exit! Add this to your main form closing event handler perhaps?
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

You'll need to add them to the settings file first though. It's easy enough in Visual Studio. In the solution explorer: Project -> Preferences -> Settings.settings.